# how to access pages with querystring using request and node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, httprequest

I wrote code for a simple web scraper using Node.js and an online tutorial to gather info for BuzzFeed quizzes. It works fine for the main page (https://www.buzzfeed.com/quizzes) but when I try to use it on any of the other pages (i.e. https://www.buzzfeed.com/quizzes?page=4), I get no results. I'm not sure what's wrong? Here's my code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/quizzes',
    qs: {
      page: 4
    }
}

request(options, function(error, response, html) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      $('div.card.js-feed-item').each(function( index ) { 
        var title = $(this).find('h2').text().trim();
        var link = $(this).find('a.link-gray').attr('href');
        var image = $(this).find('a.link-gray > div.js-progressive-image').attr('data-background-src');
        fs.appendFileSync('buzzfeed.txt', title + '\n' + link + '\n' + image + '\n\n');
      });
}});
```

Basically, if I comment out this:

```
qs: {
    page: 4
}
```

it works fine. Am I using qs wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at request done by the page , actually you can just scrap this URL : "https://www.buzzfeed.com/quizzes?render_template=0" , it gives you a json with 2 fields: cards ( array of information ) and nextPage (something like /quizzes?render_template=0&page=2) , you just could use this data I think is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the BuzzFeed server wants to send back a compressed response. If you look at the [documentation for the `request` module](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) you can find this option:

> `gzip` - If `true`, add an `Accept-Encoding` header to request compressed content encodings from the server (if not already present) and decode supported content encodings in the response.

So in your case just just adding `gzip: true` to your `options` object should work. Be warned though, depending on how much the page relies on JS to show its content, the HTML might not be what you expect.

---

How did I work this out? Well basically if you examine the returned `response` object (outside the `if` statement) you can get some pretty useful information.

For instance we can check if the `qs` option is working by checking the request url using `response.request.url` (or `response.request.href`) and seeing (via `console.log` or a debugger) that it correctly formed the query string (`?page=4`), so that's not the issue.

Digging further we can see that `response.statusCode` is `500` and `response.body` (or the `html` param) is `{"message": "INTERNAL_ERROR"}`. This seems to indicate a "server error", however we can visit the page just fine in our browser, so in reality it seems like the server just doesn't like how we formed our request for some reason.

At times like these it's worth checking out `response.headers`, where we can see e.g. that `content-type` is `application/json` (which is clearly not what you want). But more interestingly, there is a `vary` header where one of the values is `Accept-Encoding` - this is basically saying "if you make this request again with a different Accept-Encoding header, you will get a different response". [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) is almost always used to specify types of compression you can deal with, of which gzip is the most commonly supported by servers, hence the `gzip` option provided by the Node request module. If you open up the network tab of your browser devtools and browse to the URL, you can see the same header is being set (in Chrome, filter requests by "Doc" to find it more easily).

**Edit:** your original code seems to be working for me now, so maybe it was a server issue after all.